# Pass HTML table rows to Flask backend

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a Flask app where I populate an HTML table using javascript when the user presses a button. I need the info from the table passed back to the backend when the user is done with the table and presses another button. I'm trying to access the **td** elements using Flask's **request.form**

Javascript:

```
let i = 0;

function rowTemplate(i, name) {
  return `<tr data-index=${i}>
    <td>${name}</td>
  </tr>`
}

function addRow() {
  $('#my-tbody').append(rowTemplate(i, some_name));
  i++;
}
```

Jinja template:

```
<form name="my-form" method="POST" action="{{ url_for("my_func") }}">
  <table name="my-table">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="my-tbody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Flask route:

```
@app.route("/run", methods=['POST'])
def my_func():
    print(request.form)

    return render_template("my_template.jinja2")
```

The **request.form** seems to not include table and its children elements. I found a suggestion to use a *input type=hidden* tag and store the info i need there, so I can access it from **request.form** but it still doesn't show up in **request.form** if I include it in the javascript function like so:

```
let i = 0;

function rowTemplate(i, name) {
  return `<tr data-index=${i}>
    <td>${name}</td>
    <input type="hidden" name=${name} value=${i}>
  </tr>`
}
```

The hidden input element shows up in **request.form** only if I manually add it in the tbody but that doesn't work for me, I need to be adding it from the javascript function

```
<tbody id="my-tbody">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test">
</tbody>
```

I might have the wrong approach altogether. How do I get the values of the table's **td** elements to **my_func**?

Comment: Hey Welcome to Stackoverflow, I also have this kind of Code before js frameworks like vue/angular/react come up. One method is to extract the data with js out of the table,prepare and send it then as json to flask. Or you can Just use a js framework with data binding they did the Job for you. You can set and get the table from js with Ajax for example. Look into vuetify datatable. You May find alternativ datatable solutions, jqeury has also a datatable

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did it like you suggested -- one method is to extract the data with js out of the table,prepare and send it then as json to flask

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Christoph that modern javascript frameworks make developing such an application part much easier. However, an approach using input fields should send the data to the server so that it can be queried.

The following simple example may not be quite what you intend and could certainly be implemented better, but it shows you a variant that works. The user can build a table embedded in a form step by step and then send it. In order to finally make the data queryable, the mentioned input fields are used within the table.

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/func', methods=['POST'])
def func():
    print(request.form)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      table {
        width: 100%;
      }
      tr td:last-child {
        width: 10%;
        white-space: nowrap
      }
      tr td:first-child {
        padding: 0 0.6rem 0 0;
      }
      tr td > * {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .block {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="my-form" action="{{ url_for('func') }}" method="post">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="input-row">
            <td><input type="text" name="input" tabindex="0" /></td>
            <td><button type="submit">Add</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
    <button name="send-btn" class="block">Submit</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (() => {
        const form = document.querySelector('form[name="my-form"]');
        form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
          evt.preventDefault();

          const name = evt.target.input.value.trim();
          if (name.length === 0) return;

          const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
          const tr = document.createElement('tr');
          tr.innerHTML = `
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="${name}" tabindex="-1" readonly /></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="rm-btn">Remove</button></td>
          `;
          tbody.insertBefore(tr, tbody.lastElementChild);
          const btn = tr.querySelector('.rm-btn')
          btn.addEventListener('click', evt => {
            evt.target.closest('tr').remove();
          });
          evt.target.reset();
        });

        const sendBtn = document.querySelector('button[name=send-btn]');
        sendBtn.addEventListener('click', evt => {
          form.querySelector('#input-row').remove();
          form.submit();
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I was unable to make it work still. I ended up using js to extract the table data and send as json to server